# Oracle VM VirtualBox: Failed to open a session for the virtual machine

Tags: linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization, fedora

I have installed Oracle VM VirtualBox on Fedora 35 and getting the following error.

> Failed to open a session for the virtual machine Ubuntu.
> The virtual machine 'Ubuntu' has terminated unexpectedly during startup with exit code 1 (0x1).

> Result Code: NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
> Component: MachineWrap
> Interface: IMachine {85632c68-b5bb-4316-a900-5eb28d3413df}

I tried:

`dnf install akmod-VirtualBox kernel-devel-$(uname -r)`

`akmods; systemctl restart vboxdrv.service`

Any ideas to fix this?

Comment: Some things you can try - if there is saved VM state you can try discarding it, you can try updating host modules, or also reinstalling VirtualBox.

Comment: @squillman Did not work.

Comment: Is the Ubuntu VM a brand new VM?  Do you have another machine you can copy it to to see if you get the same message there?

Comment: @squillman Both the VirtualBox and the Ubuntu virtual machine are brand-new.

Comment: @squillman Disabling the secure boot worked.

Comment: Great!  I'm glad you got it working.  Thanks for posting the follow-up!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disabling the secure boot from the BIOS setting worked.